# gsutil signed URL, hide file and bucket name

Tags: download, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

So I can successfully generate a temporary signed url on google cloud storage, with an expiry time etc.

However the signed URL still has the clearly visible bucket name and file name.

Now I understand that when the download occurs, the filename will be visible.. as we have downloaded that file. However it would be nice to obscure the bucket and filename in the URL?

Is this possible, the documentation does not give any clues and a google search session has not really given any results that help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way. Bucket naming [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices) basically state that bucket and object names are "public", that you should avoid using sensitive information as part of those names, and advice you to use random names if you are concerned about name guessing/enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for this would be to proxy the "get" for the Cloud Storage objects using Cloud Functions or App Engine, so the app retrieves the objects from Cloud Storage and then send it to the client.

This is more costly, and would require to write more code.

I can think on another possible workaround which consists in protect your Signed URL by code (such as PHP), so that users cannot know what the URL is. Nevertheless, taking in account that you want to avoid any displayed-data on the network activity when downloading, you should test this workaround first to see if this works as intended.